# Facing an SocketTimeoutException while reading a register value using Modbus client

Tags: modbus-tcp

```
The exception looks like this:

    Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
        at de.re.easymodbus.modbusclient.ModbusClient.ReadInputRegisters(ModbusClient.java:1073)
        at main.main.main(main.java:37)
```

The exception is occurring when I try to read register values, specifically holding registers. It seems that it connects with the server but faces problem while reading the data. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know, why you are getting this error. Can I see your connection code. It will be much help full to connect with your system.

Comment: In addition to the code requested above (ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) please confirm that you are able to poll the device using a known good application (e.g. [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)/[mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) and, ideally, include the command line used and result in your question. This helps determine if the issue is with your code or something else (the device, network etc).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by setting:

```
readConnectiontimeout(5000);
```

The actual code:

```
modbusServer.setClientConnectionTimeout(1000000000);
```